# LaunchScreen not loading

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, splash-screen

I am using Xcode 7, Swift2, Universal, I tried many different ways to make my LaunchScreen load,have no idea what else can I try, (I set up the app icon, it shows in my iPhone and the simulator as well).
 I already deleted my launchScreen.storyboard and add a new one as File>New>UserInterface>Launch Screen, tried all steps again and still can not see the launch Screen, can someone take a look in my sequence and let me know what Am I doing wrong?

1. I have a Launch Screen.storyboard (it in not nib extension)
2. Deleted both labels on it
3. Added a ImageView
4. selected 4 constraints to 0 and updated Frames and the image enlarges to full screen
5. General TAB>AppIconsandLaunch Images>LaunchImagesSources>Selected Launch Screen. (there are two options: Launch Screen Storyboard and Main Storyboard, when I select LaunchScreen.Storyboard shows after the dropdown list is gone only: LaunchScreen without the extension)
6. Selected assets.xcassets and add a NewIosLaunchImage
7. Selected the LaunchImage and there are 9 spaces for Images (I have selected in the attributes Inspector only iOS 7 & 8)
8. Added all 9 images with the correct sizes in the containers
9. set a breakpoint in the appDelegate to stop in the launchScreen
10. Run the app, and the LaunchScreen does not load.

Any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: You can refer my answer here: [Solution for Launch Image not loading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33296032/1872233)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me, make a New Brand Assets in General > App Icons & Launch Images, leave the Launch Screen File > Blank, App Icon > Launch Images source set the name of the New Brand you made.
Go to assets.xcassets highlight the New asset you just created, in the attributes Inspector select the iOS targets, 
 Select Product menu > Clean, and run the app. Let me know if works...

Comment: I had forgotten this post, I could make it work but I did exactly what you suggested. Anyway thanks for your help...