# How can I disable default splash screen in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to disable the default splash screen, making our app load main page at first?

Answer (score 16):

There is always a loading portion. During this time a splash WILL be shown. You can customize the splash screen though.

On Android - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380138/1828637

On iOS - [iOS Launch screen in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34027270/1828637)