# React Native launch image

Tags: ios, react-native, launch-screen

How do I get a RN launch image (for an iOS app) to show up in the XCode simulator? I have Launch Image Sources set to LaunchImages, Launch Screen File set to LaunchScreen and have the files (e.g. Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png) in the Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage directory, but am not seeing the launch image showing up when I load. It still has the white screen "Powered by React Native" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the app to use your launch image and not the `.xib` launch screen file the React Native template application use by default:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be old, but alternatively you can add an `Image View` to your .xib an just place your image inside of it. I also posted a more in depth answer [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027270/ios-launch-screen-in-react-native/43566935#43566935)