# Removing launch screen in react native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am developing an app in react-native.
Whenever I start the app I am getting the below screen as the start screen.

[image]

Any idea how can I remove it?
I am new to the react-native world. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: on Which platform u see this screen ?android ?ios? both?

Comment: @rashijain: i need for both

Answer (score 0):

This screen lets your app stay up and running without delays

If you allocate to give it up
You need to change this on Android and iOS separately

For Android - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380138/9161478

For iOS - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073928/9161478