# Dark mode launch screen in iOS 13

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios13

I've updated my iOS app to work in dark mode on iOS 13 but I am having trouble trying to get the launch screen to look good.

Currently it is a bright white screen with the app logo which looks awful in dark mode. I have tried setting the background colour of the launch screen to be a colour asset that I made with "Any Appearance" being white and "Dark Appearance" being black - but the launch screen still always shows as white.

Is there any way to get my launch screen to work properly in dark mode?

Comment: Use `systemBackgroundColor` for the background color. No need for your own color asset.

Comment: That worked! If you want to post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @rmaddy do you know if this crashes the app on iOS 12 and below?

Comment: @IvanIčin It should not crash. Xcode seems to set the equivalent of the light mode color in the storyboard if you are supporting iOS 12 or lower. Try it and be sure.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When setting up the Launch Screen storyboard, set the view "Background" color to "System Background Color". This will be white in light mode and black in dark mode. No need to use your own color asset.

Comment: But if I want to override user interface style to dark in system light mode or override it to light when system is in dark mode. How can I implement it? The storyboard will always follow system background color so it will not be smooth.

Comment: @Weslie See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app?changes=latest_minor

Comment: Actually I know it, and I've succeeded change that programmatically.  The key to the problem is that I want to change that for `LaunchScreen`, as is described in this topic. For example, when system is dark, I could override current window to light, BUT the `LaunchScreen` still remains dark.

Comment: This is not nice, my app uses a colourful background for the light and black for the dark mode.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim What isn't nice? There's nothing preventing you from supporting different colors. If you have a specific issue you should post your own question with all relevant details.

Comment: By using the `System Background Color` you are forced to set your splash screen white, you cannot change this value.

Comment: Xcode should include variation based on the theme, like it does with the screen width and height.

Comment: Also named colors are only available a prior iOS 11.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim The use of system background color is specific to this question and answer. As I said, post your own question with your own specific details to get proper help with your issue.

Comment: Assuming launch screens can be only white or black is not a correct approach in my opinion. I've resolved my issue by using dynamic image assets for both background and logo.

Comment: This is correct but will not be sufficient if custom background colour is required. If custom colour/image is required to be used as a background on the Launch Screen then background need to be implemented using ImageView object and actual image asset (ie. 1px x 1px for flat colour)

Comment: Hi @Weslie , have you managed to display proper `LaunchScreeen` for your app? My app supports customized appearance as well. I have no idea how to make `LaunchScreen` consistent.

Comment: Restart Simulator after changing the color. Sometimes it does not show the changes because of the cached Storyboard.

Answer (score 26):

I found a solution that supports earlier iOS versions as well as custom colors for each mode, dark and light, in iOS 13.

1. Create an image asset, set Appearances to Any, Light, Dark, and load small solid pngs with your desired colors. In this case I am using orange for light, and black for dark.

[image: image asset]

2. Go to your LanuchScreen.storyboard and add an image view with that image asset. Place the image behind your image logo, set Content Mode as Aspect Fill, and constrain the view to the Superview in all sides. (Make sure that your logo looks good with the two backgrounds, or set its Appearance too)
3. This is where I had to do a trick. For some reason, I couldn't make the back image to show up. After checking some of the comments in [Launch Screen storyboard not displaying image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669325/launch-screen-storyboard-not-displaying-image), I added the first image in the image asset to the target bundle

The color is static in older versions of iOS, and it works well with dark and light modes in iOS 13.

Comment: Thanks! This was actually the best solution for my case. I support older versions than iOS11 and I also have a custom background color.

Comment: Thanks. Reboot my simulator fixed.. the LaunchScreen bug that not showing any images.

Comment: Thanks! I followed all your steps and finally I reboot my simulator then its worked.

Answer (score 17):

I was missing colors from my color palette in Xcode defaulty offered colors so I created my own using `Color.xcassets` where I created custom color set with appearences `Any, Dark` and set my colors.

[image]

Then I can use them in autolayout same like System Colors even in `LaunchScreen`

[image]

Comment: Please note that name color properties are only supported from iOS 11.0

Comment: For lower version use UIImageView and 1px image for both dark and light styles.

Comment: Are these images, i.e. jpgs or pngs, rather than actual UIColors? Edit: nevermind, I see you can add a color set in xcassets.

Comment: Note: I had to fully restart my device for this to take effect!

Comment: Note: like @MichealCWallas, you need to delete the app, and restart the simulator, or even executing in a new one to see the changes!

Answer (score 16):

I was updating my app to support new Dark Mode for iOS 13, I put "**System Background Color**" for the View's background in my **LanuchScreen.storyboard**, but surprisingly it didn't work!

The Logo image on the page was changing correctly based on Light/Dark Mode, but **not the background!**

I was about to apply Jose's solution, but before that, I decided to **completely remove** the app from my device and try again. And it worked!!

Answer (score 8):

Yes Launch Screen work in dark mode, First check the background colour of your "xyz" image. if it is ok. just delete you app from device or simulator, because some time Launch Screen cached by device or simulator and you will not get the update UI on it. if you will face same problem just follow my demo app github.com/Indolia/darkmode.git

Comment: Without restarting the simulator none of the other answers worked. Thanks.

Comment: Same for me, deleting the app didn't do anything but restarting the simulator worked.

Comment: I just ran the app on a new simulator , and everything worked like a charm ! Thank you .