# iOS13 launch screen theme

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I have a 2 logo for my application (logo_light.png and logo_dark.png). Depending on the ios13 theme (dark or light), I want to launch launchscreen with a light or dark version of my logo. How can i do this? The main problem is that iOS does not use logo mode when launching the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dark mode launch screen in iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892053/dark-mode-launch-screen-in-ios-13)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

First of all select `UIImageView` from your LaunchScreen and add image for Light version and then select the arrow next to your Light image like below.

[image]

Then select your image from assets and you need to change **`Appearances`**  from **none** to **Any, Dark** like below image.

[image]

so once you change **`Appearances`**  from **none** to **Any, Dark** Dark Appearances will automatically add and then you just need to set different image for light and dark Appearances like below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it seems at the time of launch (on LaunchScreen) iOS does not determine which theme is included and I always use one image.

Comment: @ВиталийМонастырев, You can check it by, Turn on **Dark Appearance** from **Developer** option of your simulator.