# launchscreen image can not show

Tags: ios

Because of Apple’s new regulations, we are going to replace launchImage with launchscreen in our project, but when we replaced it according to the tutorial and tested it, we found that sometimes the picture was not displayed and the screen was blank. So I want to ask is it possible for App Store users?

I searched for some results, but it seems to have no effect. as follows:
[Launch Screen storyboard not displaying image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669325/launch-screen-storyboard-not-displaying-image)

Answer (score 1):

There used to be problems with replacing the launch image. The system caches it somehow but I don't remember finding a good pattern.

Please try rebooting your device, see if that solves the problem.

Comment: We haven't updated the picture that replaces launchscreen, it has just been replaced by launchImage for launchscreen. Only in the development stage, there was a black screen during back and forth testing. So don’t confirm whether App Store users will also appear, and if you let App Store users uninstall the APP and restart the device, the experience will be too bad.

Comment: Of course nobody should delete the app and re-download, this bug shouldn't be happening for apps downloaded form the App Store. We're talking about a bug that happens during development, when you update your launch image/screen. Have you tried rebooting the device?

Comment: Are you sure that this will not happen to App Store users? Of course, if it is aimed at the development stage, I can solve the problem by restarting the device.

Comment: You can always make a production build and test it on TestFlight, that's as close as you can get to production without a release.