# Launch Image Not Show To Startup app

Tags: ios

I Am Developing App. Add the images on Assests.xcassests. But image not show when play app on device or simulator. Show white screen.Add images properly.Buts the reason for show white screen. Any idea. thanks in advance.

Comment: check the image size and device type. you have to add all the images for different screen sizes. Refer apple documentation - https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

Comment: Add All images on different Size with .png format.

Comment: Can you screenshot your assets ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Image not showing up in iOS application (using Images.xcassets)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723547/launch-image-not-showing-up-in-ios-application-using-images-xcassets)

Answer (score 0):

After adding images to image assets, you have to select your launch image source it like below image.

Refer this link for adding launch image: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html

[image]

Comment: this all things are same. in my project

Comment: YES. i Have done all the step.But show white screen on device and simulator

Comment: check your images which you have created

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen.storyboard ---> use as Launch Screen(cancel this option)

Comment: maybe, try dele the app and install again