# React Native iOS: Launch Screen used instead of Launch Image in build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, launchimage

I have deleted the default Launch Screen file that React Native created and instead created a Launch Image. When I run the app in the simulator the Launch Image is being displayed but when I archive the project and open it via Testflight it still shows the old React Native Launch screen. Am I missing something? Is there a cache that I'm missing? I have cleaned the project but that didn't help.

[image: Launch Screen]

[image]

Comment: Hmm interesting. A different solution could be renaming the launch image something else like 'LaunchImage2' and trying it that way. Just in case the original image is persisting somewhere.

Comment: @CaseyWest that actually helped so thank you! Still strange though

Comment: Cheers, posted an answer so I remember where this post is. Going to test and see if I can figure out why the original persists when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the launch image to 'LaunchImage2' or something similar will resolve this issue. I am going to do further research and update this answer if I find out where the original Launch Image could be persisting after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar situation.
The launch image only showed up when i deleted the app from the simulator and run the app again.

[Launch Image not showing up in iOS application (using Images.xcassets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723547/launch-image-not-showing-up-in-ios-application-using-images-xcassets)