# iOS app layout on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone

I have currently developed an iOS app. The deployment target is 7.1 and I am targeting iPhone5/5s and iPhone6/6s as main devices.

After I have finished development, my app got rejected stating that it does not support the device screen size of the iPhone6.

I have tested this app using the iPhone6 simulator and my real iPhone 6 and everything looks correct and scaled.

1. I am using AutoLayout
2. I have set constraints
3. I was using a LaunchScreen but after i read many posts i deleted the LaunchScreen and added Launch Images with all the sizes and with the correct default names.

The app review team provided me with screenshots that shows my app running on an iPhone6 however with the layout dimensions of an iPhone5s (the layout is not scaled, there is a large white border)

Could you please guys provide me with any tips?

Comment: I think you missed launch screens for iPhone 6.Go to Images.xcassets and select launch image.If it is not there add.There you need to add launch images for multiple screens.check the link for how to setup image asserts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141731/xcode-6-launch-image-does-not-show-up

Answer (score 1):

> I was using a LaunchScreen but after i read many posts i deleted the LaunchScreen and added Launch Images

That's the problem. You must use a launch screen, because otherwise your app does not run natively on iPhone 6; instead, it is treated as an iPhone 5 and scaled up, exactly as Apple's screenshots showed you. Apple will no longer accept that; you must run natively, so you must use a launch screen.

Comment: It is treated as an iPhone5 however it does not scale, it is left with large white borders. I would also like to ask you, if i use correct Launch Images that support the different sizes and with the correct default names, would that be enough? or should i add the LaunchScreen anyway?

Comment: Our app targets iOS 7.0+ and only uses launch *images*. I believe you must include a launch image for the iPhone 6 and/or launch screen. The Apple docs are confusing/misleading on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add launch images of the below resolutions to support iPhone6. Pl. refer to the below url which clearly specifies the dimension of the launch images to be used. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html