# iOS Launch Image Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

My game supports landscape and I've currently set up my launch screen to support all iPhone orientations/iOS' in my image asset folder. Yet, the launch image only shows up for the iPhone 6 Plus and not any of the other iPhone devices. I've already deleted my LaunchScreen.xib and left the section in my App General Settings, "Launch Screen File", blank.

How do I make the launch image display on all iPhone devices?

Comment: Refer this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141731/xcode-6-launch-image-does-not-show-up-in-my-ios-app & https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to images.xcassets

2.

[image: if you didn't have any launch image then add]

3.in that you will see all type of launch screen ,you have to give as per the standard width and height of the device.

i hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

you can use images.xcassets or  LaunchScreen.xib file to have launch screen for all devices . if you choose xib try to make it auto layout . if you define auto layout in interface xib file you can determine the all objects' positions in your launch screen for all devices