# Why isn't my launch image loading when the app starts?

Tags: ios, xcode7

I have been reading through all the answers, but still can't figure out to what I'm doing wrong. I went to `Project` -> `General` -> `Launch Image Source` and set that field to LaunchImage, which is in my `Assets.xcassets`. I have left `Launch Screen File` field empty. I read at several places to delete `LaunchScreen.xib` file, but I don't have that in my Xcode project. I also have the right sizes of images that are required by apple for Launch Images. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Project and go tab General. Make sure you have set image folder and remove lauchscreen.xib

[image]

Select arrow and go to folder. make sure you check:

[image]

Maybe it will help you.

But I strongly recommend you: use lauchscreen.xib or .storyboard. It is more better than using lauchImage. If you use lauchingScreen, you should use like this::

Drag image to xib , and set image to this imageview check option use as lauch screen on right side of xib file. It will work like a charm :)

Comment: what does it mean to remove lauchscreen.xib? I'm really confused on that. Is that file? Where wil I find that in order to remove it? Also, I have all these options checked.

Comment: @Sharukh you let this filed empty.

Comment: i read through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141731/xcode-6-launch-image-does-not-show-up-in-my-ios-app and someone said to also delete `info.plist` item. I think only not deleting that might be causing the problem. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Sharukh if delete just delete field `Launch screen interface file base name`. But why you don't use lauching.xib or storyboard.

Comment: @Sharukh oops but above I see that you describe is remove it lol (rofl) what wrong here T_T

Comment: @Sharukh if you lauchingscreen.xib or storyboard. Modify this file add imageview to it, and set image to this imageview check option use as lauch screen on right side.

Comment: @Sharukh can you accept my anser? I will edit my answer for your case

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the launchscreen image as the background image of you launchscreen.storyboard

Comment: will try right now, but just wondering that what if I want to refer to `Assets.xcassets`? That is how it is right now, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding the retina images to your app. For me this did the trick. No launch image was shown on my simulator before adding them.

Please remember that you need portrait and landscape if your app does both.

LI retina 5.5 is size 1242x2208 retina 4.7 is 750x1334 (portrait) and opposite for landscape is true ie. retina 5.5 2208x1242 4.7 1334x750

[Retina launch images are needed for ios 8/9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap0br.png)

Comment: umm. I had for the sizes including th retina, but that didn't seem to do the trick either.