# Launch screen is not showing in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app the launch screen is showing in iPhone 5s, but it is not showing in any other iPhone, like "iPhone 8+", "iPhone 11 Pro Max" or "iPhone 12 Pro Max".

In the plist file I have added a key "Launch image".

How can I show the launch screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your problem and it seems like there is a small confusion while adding launch image in info.plist , may be you can check this link if that can help you out here.
[Launch Image does not show up in my iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141731/launch-image-does-not-show-up-in-my-ios-app)