# UIWindow not filling screen for new devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate, uiwindow

I'm working with an old Xcode project which is roughly 7/8 years old and I've migrated it to Objective-C 2.0 and to support ARC. The project didn't support Auto-Layout (this was just before it was released) prior to me working on it. I've managed to clear up a lot of the errors/issues i was having with running it in a more modern Xcode IDE (10.2.1). For testing purposes I have implemented this code into the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height)];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

self.window.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

which gives me this for some reason:

[image]

This is the result when i run on a iPhone X, iPhone XR or iPhone XS Max, it looks like the top and bottom margins (safe areas) of the screen are not being picked up on. When i debug the view hierarchy they aren't being picked up on either, it just shows the red space? When i throw this code in a new project it works fine and fills up all the space. I'm wondering that because this is a old project there might be a build setting which is restricting the `UIWindow` from expanding to allow support for new devices?

Also as a side note I've made sure the `UIWindow` object isn't being manipulated elsewhere.

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639233/iphone-app-is-running-at-iphone-4-size-with-black-bars-after-update

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to add "Launch screen interface file base name" (`UILaunchStoryboardName`) to your Info.plist

It seems that the presence of this key tells the system that you natively support new device types and size classes, so your window can fill all available area.

Comment: Thank you! Been on a wild goose chase for hours now - this is so odd. Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess with the storyboard.
Add `UILaunchScreen` dictionary entry to your .plist.
Include `UIColorName` string value with background color name defined in the `Assets.xcassets`.

```
    <key>UILaunchScreen</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIColorName</key>
        <string>launchScreenBackground</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Nice! This should be the accepted answer if you do not use storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a setting specifically to auto-generate an empty launch screen: `INFOPLIST_KEY_UILaunchScreen_Generation` if you don't want to do anything custom.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#Launch-Screen-Generation