# SwiftUI - LaunchImage not showing

Tags: swift, swiftui, asset-catalog

I cannot get a Launch Image to be displayed on my app, whatever I try.
For context, this is a completely new, 100% SwiftUI project and is in its very early infancy.

Everything builds & runs perfectly fine, but I just cannot get any launch image customisation going...

My `Info.plist`:
[image: info.plist]

My assets:
[image: asset catalog]

I've tried cleaning, deleting DerivedData, reinstalling app on device + sim but to no avail...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue before and got it fixed by restarting my phone.

See also: [iOS launch screen does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192425/ios-launch-screen-does-not-update)

Answer (score 3):

When using launch storyboards I found that if the images that I used where too large it would launch with a black screen.

I reduced the size of the images I was using (one was reduced to 900px by 700px) but I don't know the magical size that sorts it, I then rebooted my iPhone and it started to work fine.

I don't know if the size issue would affect normal launch images but it may be worth giving it a try with a smaller image.

Comment: Thanks for your insights @J_B_UK! I guess it might be related to that; as I used as large an image as I could, hoping it'd be properly scaled for the device running the app...

Comment: It also helped, I was using image with 1024*1024 and it was not showing from the Stroyboard, than I added small image it get worked with me.