# ios 9, white splash screen instead of launch image, working fine previously, seemingly nothing changed to cause it

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, launch, launchimage

When my app launches, I see a white screen, instead of my launch image. I am using a storyboard, as required, and everything was working fine for about 2 months before this. I didn't change anything related to the image or storyboard either, it just started happening. I should mention that this started happening sometime after my first time uploading to `TestFlight`...but I doubt that is relevant. I have tried changing the `constraints` of the image to make it smaller than the bounds, and it still doesn't show up, so it isn't the size of the image. Again, I seemingly did nothing to have this start happening. Most of the questions related to my problem on `stackoverflow` have to do with the user not using a storyboard as required with iOS 9. Please help. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I launched it on the simulator (iPad2) and the launch image for that was too small...there was white exposed above and to the right, I'm guessing I need to fix something in the storyboard but I'm not sure what.

**UPDATE**

I made a new storyboard and assigned the launch-screen config to it, and there is still a white screen.

Comment: Do you see a LaunchScreen.storyboard file in your project?

Comment: yah...its what i have been using

Comment: Can you share the Launch screen and image asset

Comment: the actual files or pictures? i can do either

Comment: this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002829/ios-keeping-old-launch-screen-and-app-icon-after-update

Answer (score 0):

1. I deleted the `UIImageView` and then inserted a new one with dimensions 200 x 200.
2. I added the image to the `UIImageView`.
3. I adjusted the constraints to the same values that I was using before.

Adding the image to the 200 x 200 `UIImageView`, before adding the constraints, seemed to be the key.

Comment: In my case, I deleted the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and created it again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that one of the view controllers has the `Is Initial View Controller` checkbox checked in the `Attributes Inspector` in the right sidebar, that got me.

Answer (score 0):

In project by default you LauchScreen.xib. Put your launch image there and set it’s top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints. Tap your project file and scroll down. There you will see: LauchScreen option and MainStoryboard. Set LauchScreen to your LauchScreen.xib. That’s it))