# Appicon in iOS app not changing while pushing a new build to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

While pushing a new build of my iOS app to TestFlight I am changing the app icon. But when looking at the All Builds > Activity, in iTunesConnect I can still see the old app icon. I have changed the appicon in my project in Xcode. But I can still see the old appicon when I install the app via TestFlight which changes later to the new appicon.

Comment: I used this plugin to Xcode for automatic icon generation: https://github.com/kaphacius/IconMaker .

Comment: I know how to create the icons. But the problem is that the icons are not changing. Thanks.

Comment: There is a fix for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002829/ios-keeping-old-launch-screen-and-app-icon-after-update/33003622#comment81478861_35783070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple uses some cache to make the application switching faster. This will get resolved when the the Springboard takes snapshot of your application ,which is going to happen soon. This is a bug in Apple's code and there is nothing you can do about it.

> SpringBoard is the application that manages the home screen on iOS devices. With SpringBoard, icons on the home screen can be organized,
>   the background wallpaper changed, and applications are launched. Some
>   of the iPhone's settings at startup are also set by the SpringBoard.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "Springboard takes snapshot of your application" what exactly does it mean?