# iOS Keeping old launch screen after update

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS app currently running in Appstore. I am in the process of updating the app’s Launch image.

Previously the app had a Launch screen image which was added in LaunchScreen.storyboard and in the update I changed it into static LaunchImage files, for a new install all works fine but for upgrading users the app keeps showing the old image.

I tried to test it with TestFlight but I still get the same results.

Stuff that I tried to do fix the issue

1. Deleted the old images from the project
2. removed the LaunchScreen.storyboard from the project,
3. Deleted the derived data of the app
4. Deep clean Build

but the problem still continues for upgrading users.

Suggestions are welcome

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35783070/4284508

Comment: I'm running into exactly the same scenario.  I changed from storyboard to a LaunchImage and on the upgrade scenario the old launch screen still shows.  I guess we can not change the launch screen method in this way.

Answer (score 0):

**I think-**

You need to check your `Assets.xcassets` folder.

[image]

If your images exist here, Just move to trash and add new one again.

Comment: I tried it already.. It doesn't work in this case. Thanks