# Why is my App Store build only partially upgrading previous versions of my app?

Tags: ios, react-native, redux

I have a React Native app in the Apple App Store and recently released a new version.  I'm getting reports from existing users who already had the previous version of the app installed that their new install is either partially upgrading or not upgrading at all, even though the app store is showing that the new version is installed.

In the app store they are seeing the new version number.  They do the upgrade and then see the Open button, indicating that the upgrade is complete.

Some users are reporting that they see the old versions splash screen and then the new version of the app is there.  Others are reporting that the old app hasn't changed at all even though, as I mentioned, the app store is showing the new one is installed.  If the user deletes the app and installs it clean then it is always properly installing the new version.

Any idea why this may be happening?  I would think that an upgrade scenario would be simply keeping the app data around while removing the old binary and replacing with the new binary.

I did switch the splash screen loading method from Launch Screen in the old version to Launch Images in the new one.  And I have had many javascript changes and new native libraries installed.  And my redux store has some different data structures.  But I don't know why any of these things would result in a partial upgrade.

Comment: Are you using anything like Expo or CodePush?

Comment: I have the code push library installed, but haven't used it in months.

Comment: Ohh!  I wonder if it's overwriting my javascript with the old version?

Comment: Yes. I think that's what's possibly causing this. The loading screen issue is slightly different but unrelated - because the loading screen needs to be loaded *immediately* when the user opens the app, it's cached at an OS level and can sometimes show the old one.

Comment: After upgrading to a new app version would code push still keep showing the old javascript even the first time the new app is launched?  Or would it show the new version's javascript the first time the app is run and then download the code push image for subsequent versions?  I have the checkFrequency set to `CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME`.

Comment: It looks like this is causing my splash screen issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533133  Apparently you can't change from storyboard launch screens to a LaunchImage.  Perhaps that is causing the error upgrading as well.