# Trouble with changing image on splashscreen

Tags: ios, image, launch

everyone. I have one more question about trouble with changing the picture on the launch screen. If you change your picture on launch screen, you will see your old picture. I read about it [iOS Keeping old launch screen and app icon after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002829/ios-keeping-old-launch-screen-and-app-icon-after-update). How long you will see your old picture if you don’t restart your device?

Comment: Weirdly uninstalling and restarting the device only works. Apple should change the way how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:-

- Uninstall App.
- Restart Device.

Note:- This issue will not come in Simulator

Comment: a know about this solution, but I'm interested, will the screen change over time? maybe cache would modified?