# splash screen logo image not shown using xcode 10 in swift

Tags: ios, xcode10

I am updating my code Xcode 9.2 to latest Xcode 10. all things working properly but splash screen logo image not shown when apps running .  is there any solution for it.

Comment: Simply restart the device. iOS caches the launch screen per app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See previous answers here: [iOS Keeping old launch screen and app icon after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002829/ios-keeping-old-launch-screen-and-app-icon-after-update)

You don't specify in the question if you're running on a real device or simulator, but if simulator make sure you do 'Erase All Content And Settings' from the 'Hardware' menu. The simulator is not an emulator and doesn't always behave the same as a real device.

Answer (score 2):

I got solution for my problem by restarting testing device.