# LaunchScreen not showing up on any devices and projects

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, storyboard, simulator

I tried server methods to fix this problem, but nothing seems to work. The `launchScreen` won't show up on any devices or any project. Even in the simulator the launchScreen is not showing up.

**I added `background color` and a `imageView` to my launchScreen.**

This is what I already tried:

set it to initialViewController

add new viewController and deleted the old one

changed the name in the info.plist

Comment: this question needs more detail, it is too short say anything. Please add what you have done to show the launch screen and what are the different fixes you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be, you catched the bug which prevents updating of LaunchScreen.
There are some methods to fix it.
For me only helped removing of LaunchScreen file, recreating new one, cleaning project and removing the app with device reboot before new install.

[iOS Keeping old launch screen and app icon after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002829/ios-keeping-old-launch-screen-and-app-icon-after-update)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that Launch Screen Filename is correctly set.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There could be couple of possibilities.

1. Confirm that your launch screen has `Is Initial View Controller` check on. It is indicating that storyboard is a entry point of launch.

[image]

2. Your `Launch Screen File` name should be correct. You can find the same in `General` tab of project target.

[image]

3. Check Target Membership for Launch Screen.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for all 3 possibilities?

Comment: Yes, this is all equal