# How to remove flutter_native_splash from app?

Tags: flutter

I used `flutter_native_splash: ^1.3.2` for splash screen, i want to remove this splash screen.

Below code is in `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffffff"
  image: assets/images/AppLogo.png
  android: true
  ios: true
```

I used `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove` command to remove,
And i also remove **flutter_native_splash (Above code)** dependency from `pubspec.yaml`file.
And then i clean my project using flutter clean command.
then get the packages.
So now when i run the app it shows the splash screen which i removed.
so please Help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I've tried everything and cannot get rid of this thing when I run my app on a physical device (didn't try on emulator)

Answer (score 3):

*Worked for me:*
**`flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove`**

*but at first I got an error that I don’t have such a package*

> because before that I tried to manually remove this package

- *added again to the project*
- *Then run the `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove` in **terminal***

*error:*

flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove
Could not find package "flutter_native_splash". Did you forget to add a dependency?
pub finished with exit code 65

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/53) on how to uninstall the package, this is a generator and you also have to remove the generated files.
So ideally, if you have version control you could just revert you changes when adding the files.
Else you have to manually remove the changes such as the  `launch_background.xml, styles.xml` etc.

You can get a good hint which files might be affected by scanning the [templates](https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/blob/master/lib/templates.dart) of this package.

Answer (score 0):

iOS has a known caching issue that maintains a splash screen even after it has been removed.  If the problem is on iOS, it may be cause by [this caching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002829/ios-keeping-old-launch-screen-and-app-icon-after-update).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It is because of the cache in the device. Once you erase the all cache, the old one will disappears. In iOS simulator, you can do this by selecting menubar => Erase all contents and setting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of possible solutions but in the end, none of them worked. But since we actually don't write code directly in the android folder I thought the easiest option would be to delete the android folder from the root folder. Then use

```
flutter create create -i swift -a kotlin <project_name>
```

or

```
flutter create .
```

This will create the new folders. You just need to make changes to the build files (for android, the build.gradle in your /android and /android/app folders if required) in these newly created folders which might some take time. Just gloss over the backups to make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple just write.

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove
   this is the simplest way to remove flutter native splash.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I finally decided to behave this way.

flutter_native_splash:

color: "#ffffff"

image: assets/images/img.png

android: false

ios: false

web: false

Answer (score 0):

**Required settings for Android**

— First, we find the place in the image

[Android Directory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En9Fr.png)

— We find styles.xml files in these files

[styles.xml files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWRwR.png)

— We remove the parts in each file that add the splash screen by default

[Part to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrVxL.png)

— We add the following code to the deleted places as in the image

[Part to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvqH2.png)

```xml
<!-- Disabled Default Splash -->
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

for android

go to android/app/src/main/res/drawable

replace

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item>
          <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
      </item>
      <item>
          <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
      </item> </layer-list>
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

and delete background image

Comment: It's commented out by default, that doesn't affect anything.