how to remove flutter native splash screen
I used flutter native splash package for my application. but now I want to remove it and use the default native splash screen of flutter. how to do it? thanks.
this is the Method I've done:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#071b5d"
  image: assets/logos/splash_screen_logo.png
  android: true
  ios: true


You could find your answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180530/how-to-remove-flutter-native-splash-from-app

You cannot remove the native splash screen as rightly said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895574/22178475
But you can surely customize it if you want.

Write this code in your styles.xml file inside the style area:
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

