# Flutter splash screen Xcode white background for first 2 seconds

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

**Flutter splash screen Xcode white background for first 2 seconds. After that, it correctly shows the images from my storyboard**... I tried everything to get rid of that first white blank screen, but I can't. Can someone help, please?

1. Removed Launchscreen.storyboard and regenerated.
2. Removed app from
   device and reinstalled
3. Tried everything here:
   [Launch Screen not displaying iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605562/launch-screen-not-displaying-ios-8)
4. Changed these configurations.

[image]

Bot nothing works at all. I am using `Flutter` and `flutter_native_splash` and generated the icons with this, but they did not help either.

Note: I noticed that I only see `launchscreen` and `main` as options in **general > app icons and launch images** in Xcode. Shouldn't I be able to see the option **launschreen_storyboard** as well?
Note: Android works fine. It only is a problem at iOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by restarting my device. Apparently this is an iPhone/iOS cache bug.