# LaunchScreen.xib not displaying my custom font

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using a label to display text with my custom font on LaunchScreen.xib. My custom font shows up fine in the Interface Builder, but when I test it on my iPhone the font reverts back to the default font.

Not sure how to fix this or if it's a bug.

Comment: I guess I'm not surprised. The launch screen is shown at launch time - actually, _before_ launch time - so the font probably hasn't yet loaded.

Comment: It sounds like there's no way to fix it then? Would I just be better off using a launch image?

Comment: 1) Use image 2) Use system fonts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts with Xcode 6 / iOS 8 Interface Builder Launch Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794314/using-custom-fonts-with-xcode-6-ios-8-interface-builder-launch-screen)

Comment: @NobodyNada The problem with that "duplicate" is there's no satisfactory answer there.

Comment: I would just omit the element with the text in it. Launch images are supposed to be minimal - just the bare outline of the structure, which gets filled in when the real interface appears.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There's no big surprise here. The launch screen is shown at launch time - actually, before launch time - so the font probably hasn't yet loaded.

You could file a bug if you think you have a compelling use case. But I don't really think you do. Why are you showing *any* text in your launch image? It should be much more bare-bones than that - just enough to give the structure of the opening interface, which will be filled in when the opening interface actually appears. A "blank" screen with the same background color as the initial view controller's background color would be sufficient. You goal is just to provide an alternative to blackness.

Comment: The idea was to have my app's title on that screen with a consistent font throughout the app. Ended up adding a UIImage of my title to the xib instead.

Comment: Also, Apple's default "LaunchScreen.xib" has the app's name in a plain ol' UILabel... The least we can do is select a font.... :)

Comment: @AlexZak You can select a font. Just not a font loaded in your app bundle. Besides, you're expected to delete that label.

Comment: @matt You're right, I meant select a custom font... But I'm not sure you're "expected" to delete it, we had to push an app really fast, and forgot to update the launch screen, and apple approved nonetheless...

Comment: Do what you want with your app. Apple guidelines are very explicite on how splash screens should be, it's up to you to adhere to it or not.

Comment: It amazes me that there's any argument at all against showing ones company name in their launch screen.

Comment: You make a good point. But no need to yell. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Aaargh! Just spent like half a day trying to figure out what was going on until I narrowed it down to my custom font not working on only the launch screen storyboard.  Explanation completely makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

A quick workaround is to use an `UIImageView` and have your text as `UIImage` on it, literally a picture of your text as `.png` / `.jpeg` or similar.

**Note:** It may take some time before you can see the image, I had to clean the Build Folder and reinstall the app a couple of times in order to see the image.

**Another note:** If you want to support multiple languages with different texts you will need to have different images for each language using this approach.