# Simulator not displaying custom font (tried several approaches already)

Tags: ios, xcode

I just installed a custom font and started from my launching screen. Apparently its not displaying in the simulator. I have already tried lots of approaches, including deleting app from simulator, cleaning and running again. Below you can find the current status:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to display the font in the launch screen or in the main storyboard?

Comment: In the LaunchScreen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LaunchScreen.xib not displaying my custom font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443864/launchscreen-xib-not-displaying-my-custom-font)

Comment: You can't display a custom font in the launch screen because the launch screen is displayed by the OS, not your app, and so the font is never loaded.  If you make your text an image, then you can put it in the launch screen.