# ios custom font with splash screen

Tags: ios, uilabel, splash-screen, font-style

I want to set custom font style "peach-sundress.ttf" in label of **Splash screen**, i added custom font in my project & its work fine at design time but the same is not effective at run time.

please look at below snap.

**Storyboard layout & preview:**

[image]

**Simulator[Device] View**

[image]

How can i set custom font style in a label of splash screen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443864/launchscreen-xib-not-displaying-my-custom-font