# LaunchScreen in simulator for iPhone 6 differs with physical iPhone 6

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-simulator, ios9, launch-screen

I have an issue where the launchscreen of my Swift / iOS app differs when running it on the Simulator for an iPhone 6 and on an actual device itself.

On the simulator all objects are shown and positioned correctly

[image]

When running the same app on my iPhone 6 the logo is not shown.

[image]

The constraints for the image are not extraordinary;

- Align center X to superview. Constant=0, Prio=1000, Multiplier=1
- Align center y to superview. Constant=1, Prio=1000, Multiplier=7/9
- 1:1 Ratio to Logo.png. Constant=0, Prio=1000, Multiplier=1:1

Source is avalailble on my Github repo 
https://github.com/petervannes/homecaremonitor

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579150/uiimageview-missing-images-in-launch-screen-on-device it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Make sure that the `Clears Graphics Context` box is unchecked for  the `UIImageView` in the storyboard. Just changing this fixed it for me.May be you try it out.

[[image]

**Option 2:**

Turn if off and then on again.
`restart the device`

Comment: Yeah :-) Thanks ! Needed to follow option 1 AND option 2.