# Xcode launch image for different targets

Tags: ios, xcode, image, target, launch-screen

I've created **different Targets** in my Xcode project to version my app for different clients. **Each client uses different xcassets**, one for each target. This way I can have different images with the same names. So **just by selecting the target, the correct image will show**.

This works for any view in my app. Whenever I run the app in a different target, all the images change automatically. The problem is when I have an image in my Launch Screen. **I created .xib files for my Launch Screen (one for each client)**.

By selection the target, the correct .xib runs, but the image that it loads is always the same from the base project.

---

This is how I organised the project so having different targets would automatically pick different images:

- **Base.xcassets:**

  1. Target Membership = Base
  2. image-launch (base project launch screen)
  3. Other images for base project
- **Client1.xcassets:**

  1. Target Membership = Client1
  2. image-launch (client 1 version launch screen)
  3. Other images for client 1 version
- **Client2.xcassets:**

  1. Target Membership = Client2
  2. image-launch (client 2 version launch screen)
  3. Other images for client 2 version

When I select a target, all elements with that **Target Membership** should be loaded. Only my **Launch Screen** loads the image-launch from the **Base.xcassets**.

Comment: You sure you check on each xcassets the right target and unchecked the others ?

Comment: Yes. Every single xcasset has only the correct target selected.

Comment: You've nuked Derived Data and cleaned?

Comment: Just did that. But it didn't work anyway. AND, I deleted from my mac the image that shows in the app. I was trying to force client 2 image to load. Somehow the baseapp image loads. I don't even have it in my mac anymore.

Comment: Another update: I was doing all this testing in iPhone. Then I tested it in the simulator. In the simulator it worked just fine. Now I am concerned that this could happen when I upload the app to the AppStore.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. app icons work for new target but launch image refers back to original target

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, and solved it by restarting the iOS Device. It seems that iOS caches the Launch Images/Screens, and when the developer changes the Launch Screen in XCode, these changes do not always appear on the device due to this cache. Got this solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33698093/4337911

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and finally solved this: (I am using Xcode 11.3 now)

- Select your target from the project navigator and select target's "**All**" or "**Customized**" settings
- Go to **Build Settings->Asset Catalog Compiler**
- Change value for **Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name**

Or

- Select your target from the project navigator
- Search "**Launch Image**" and change LaunchImage name in "**Asset Catalog Compiler**" section.

[image]

If the new launch screens do not show, try deleting your app and install it again.

Also, make sure the **Launch Screen File** option in your target's General Settings is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Mohit Kumar did not work for me, Maybe it is an XCode Bug (12.0.1)
What worked for me was to create different LaunchScreen files for each target.