# How to setup launch Screen for universal correctly?

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I have no idea how to solve my launch screen for iPad. I purposely created a new project which supports for universal. Same image name but it works for new project but my old project its not displaying out. it shows a white blank screen. May I know what is the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your LaunchScreen file is selected in the **Project General** Settings, like so:

[image]

Also, if you're using a storyboard for your Launch Screen, make sure there the only view controller is set as **initial view controller.**, like so:

[image]

EDIT:

So if restarting the device did not work for you, try the following:

1. Re-adding the image into your Assets.xcassets.
2. Renaming the image.
3. And from this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35481616/3231194, try unchecking the `Clears Graphics Context` of your `UIImageView`.

[image]

Comment: Yea all the setting I did follow exactly the same as above. The strange thing is the new project is working but the old project its not working at all. the new project I just put the image and auto layout for universal, it works perfectly! However, when I followed the steps to implement old project, its not working... May I know why?

Comment: Ah! Have you tried restarting your device? It happens to me sometimes in my project when I have to change the launch screen image to a new one, and I can see the old one popping up before the new one. Try restarting your device, also: clean the build and clean the project. CMD+Shift+K and CMD+Shift+Alt/option+K.

Comment: Hi, I did try your method, it still doesnt work at all. still displaying white screen. then I try to add label, it works. Just that the specific image is not working...and I tried for other image, it works also. I don't know why it doesnt load the specific image. But for new project it works! Is it a bug?

Comment: Yes, it is working for now! May I know why do I have to uncheck that? but for new project it doesn't?

Comment: That's great! I'm not sure the meaning of clearing the graphic context of a `UIView`, I don't want to give an assumption as it may give you a wrong information. But here's a documentation of Apple about `Graphic Context`: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `PNG` image, make sure that `Alpha` is unchecked while saving the image.