# Launch Screen Not Updating in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

IDE: Xcode 9.0

My app has an older launch screen that I want to replace with a new one.  Trouble is, none of the changes I make to my Launch Screen.storyboard file will show up in Simulator or on devices unless I erase all content and settings first.

I can't seem to find anything wrong in build settings, but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing the **old** launchscreen before the **new** one, then I'd say it's normal. It happens to me too. I'm certain that this does not happen in production (app from App Store).

If you just cannot see the image you're trying to show in your launchscreen nib or storyboard, I've posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46398588/3231194

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for.  I'll update this thread as to whether or not it ends up happening in production.

Comment: I am getting the new launch screen in the TestFlight version of my app, so it looks like this issue doesn't effect the production version.  Looks like the solution is just erase all content and settings in simulator to be able to preview it, and then it will work fine when pushed to production.