# The launch screen image not showing up on my ios app on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, xcode9

I have an ios app but am trying to add a launch image to the start.  I am testing on an old ios 6 phone (which I think is the retina 4.7).  I added the launch image in assets catalog like

[image]

I then have it mentioned like so:

[image]

When I run the app on my iPhone 6 device it has no load screen.  What am I missing?  I used to have a LaunchScreen.storyboard but I have all these images of the right size made and want to use those.

Comment: What is the size of the image the you uploaded for `Retina HD 4.7`?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before and I believe it's a bug with Xcode. It will still be trying to use the LaunchScreen.storyboard file.

Try the following:

1. Clean your project.
2. Delete the app from the device/simulator.
3. Restart Xcode/Simulator and re-run.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33698093/5032154 for more info.